# How do I get compiler error locations to show up in the Locations tab so I can one-click to them?

Tags: gnat-gps

I'm using Gnat Programming Studio for Ada development. How do I get the Locations tab show compiler error links so I can one click to them? I get errors in the Messages tab, but then have to manually open the file and navigate to the error location.

At a previous job, compiler error locations would show up in the Locations tab, allowing a single click to take me to the error line. At this job, they don't. I didn't do setup at either location, merely copied an existing setup. Clearly there's a difference in the two locations' GPS setup, but I don't know what it is. I've tried looking through the GPS help and preferences, as well as on line searches, and so far haven't found any answers. I don't know much about GPS internals, so I don't even know if this needs a plugin we might not have here that my previous employer did have.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question on Sunday. On Monday, I asked the question in a meeting at work, and a coworker remarked that removal of the -gnatv flag would result in the desired behavior. Apparently you can either get verbose error messages, or have the behavior I was looking for. Not sure why, but...